# I am facing a nagging issue, with 'npm install' in the pipeline; at times pipeline is failed to build the 'webdriverio' test project after checkout

Tags: javascript, typescript, node-modules, webdriver-io

Below is the following error, thrown while preparing tests for run,

```
> edgedriver@5.3.7 install /runner/_work/mypages-E2E-automated-tests/mypages-E2E-automated-tests/node_modules/edgedriver
> test -f ./dist/install.js && node ./dist/install.js || echo "Skipping install, project not build!"

/runner/_work/mypages-E2E-automated-tests/mypages-E2E-automated-    tests/node_modules/edgedriver/dist/install.js:1
import path from 'node:path';
   ^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
Skipping install, project not build!

 > geckodriver@4.2.1 postinstall /runner/_work/mypages-E2E-automated-tests/mypages-E2E-     automated-tests/node_modules/geckodriver
 > test -f ./dist/install.js && node ./dist/install.js || echo "Skipping install, project not build!"

/runner/_work/mypages-E2E-automated-tests/mypages-E2E-automated-      tests/node_modules/geckodriver/dist/install.js:1
import os from 'node:os';
   ^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
Skipping install, project not build!
```

Below is the screenshot of the package.json :

[image]

Screenshot of tsconfig.json :

[image]

I tried to update versions of webdriverio and devtools

Comment: what's your Node.js version?

Comment: Please see [ask]. Text must not be presented as images. Also, your title should be a clear, specific question. Take the [tour] to learn more.